# Can you tell me the meaning fromdate-0.0142 in oracle query

Tags: database, oracle

```
select 
id_no, nvl(OD_PLACECODE,-1) OD_PLACECODE, nvl(PURPOSECODE,-1) PURPOSECODE
from tonduty
where
to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') between fromdate-0.0142 and 
todate 
and
actinact =1;
```

can you please tell me the meaning of `fromdate-0.0142` in the above query.

Please find the sample data in fromdate field.

```
01-06-2019 09:00:00
04-06-2019 08:00:00
01-06-2019 09:00:00
04-06-2019 10:00:00
```

`fromdate` datatype is `DATE` in oracle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Its not a homework. I will explain you clearly.

In our office we have an attendance system(employee should swipe id card while entering and while leaving from the office).

If some one wants to go out for office work(on duty), they need to apply for OD. We will save that information in `ONDUTY` Table while applying for OD. after applying, they will swipe id card (In the back end software we will check whether that employee applied for the OD, IF yes we will consider it as OD OUT. If not applied for OD, we will consider it as OUT.)

In that back ground checking, we have written this query.

Comment: Looks like a homework. tell us what did you try?

Comment: Why do you run `TO_DATE()`  on a value which is already a `DATE`?

Comment: I did not run to_date() @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: @kalyan - yes you did: `to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss')`. Where `sysdate` is already a date. You are implicitly converting it to a string then explicitly back to a date, which does nothing at best, or might break with different NLS settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In date arithmetic, we are subtracting number of **days** from some date. It means the following:

```
SQL> select 0.0142 days,
  2         0.0142 * 24 hours,
  3         0.0142 * 24 * 60 minutes
  4  from dual;

      DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES
---------- ---------- ----------
     ,0142      ,3408     20,448

SQL>
```

As you can see, 0.0142 isn't a *nice* number; it represents 20 minutes (and 26.88 seconds, as 0.448 * 60 = 26.88).

Why is it subtracted from the date value, I have no idea.

**Based on your comment** (allowing 20 minutes): ask the author (of that code) why didn't they use 20 minutes, then, but 20.448? Here's how:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - 20 / (24 * 60) twenty_minutes_ago
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE             TWENTY_MINUTES_AGO
------------------- -------------------
05.06.2019 11:21:10 05.06.2019 11:01:10
```

20 minutes is `0.013888889`, not `0.0142`.

```
SQL> select 20 / (24 * 60) twenty_minutes
  2  from dual;

TWENTY_MINUTES
--------------
    ,013888889

SQL>
```

which means that your code should have been

```
between fromdate - 0.01389 and todate
```

or, even better

```
between fromdate - (20 / (24 * 60)) and todate
```

Comment: reason is. we are checking if that person applied for OD. suppose person applied OD from morning 10am TO 12AM. But he might swipe card before 10am so we are allowing them even if they swipe before 20 min also we are considering as OD out instead of OUT. @Littlefoot

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation. I edited my answer by adding some more info. Have a look, please.